# Newly installed xubuntu doesn't start

Tags: boot, xubuntu, busybox

I installed xubuntu instead of normal ubuntu i asked about yesterday, but now i have another problem. I already installed system, but I can't boot it.

After grub and "choose system to boot" window there is a cursor flashing in top-left corner and after that I receive a message:

```
Gave up waiting for a root device. common problems:
- boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/48eac13e-a49f-4c5c-bb25-cb81b900bbbe does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (sh)
Enter'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

And that is all I can do. After booting system in a safe (or recovery? I don't remember the name) I also can see a long list of things performed, but the result is the same. Message as above.

I installed Xubuntu on the same disk with WinXP. LiveCD (or rather LiveUSB) runs normally, even fast.

My computer has Pentium 4 2.4 GHz, Asus P4V8X-X Motherboard, 768 MB RAM, Radeon 9200, 120GB Samsung HDD (not even SATA).

EDIT:
I chose option to install New Xubuntu on the place after unsuccessful installation of previous ubu, which is an option "Windows and Ubu side by side" or something. Nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

based on `ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/48eac13e-a49f-4c5c-bb25-cb81b900bbbe does not exist.`, it looks like GRUB is struggling to find the hard drive partition you specified for the installation.

It's probably a good idea to re-run the installation and double check you're happy with your partition layouts, particularly if you've specified anything non-standard.

Comment: I've tried other versions of ubuntu (Polish remix of ubu 10.04), so it isn't the reason, and I used another partition layout suggested by more familiar friend. And effect is as above. And I don't even know what is uuid made of and how it's calculated. Installer doesn't ask about it or use it in any place of installation.